# Multilanguage field in Alfresco: cannot get local value

Tags: locale, alfresco

I am creating an alfresco custom type with a multilingual property:

```
<property name="xxx:myfield">
      <type>d:mltext</type>
</property>
```

When I save a new node, I receive a `language` containing the locale to apply and I do the following:

```
    Locale locale;
    if (language == null || language.isEmpty()) {
        locale = new Locale("en");
    } else {
        locale = new Locale(language);
    }

    MLText myfieldML = new MLText();
    myfieldML .addValue(locale, "someValue");

    Map<QName, Serializable> props = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>();
    props.put(QName.createQName(getNamespaceModel(), "myfield"),
            myfieldML);
```

And then I invoke the createNode method of NodeService to save the new node. That seems to work fine, as I get two locales store for the same node and I can see them in Share (if I change the browser default language, I get two different values for the two languages I created).

Now, I am not sure how to get the value for `myfield` for a given node and for a given `locale`. My current code is:

```
nodeService.getProperty(currentNode, myFieldQName)
```

I would expect to get a MLText and, from it, get the value for my locale via `getValue(locale)`. Conversely, getProperty returns a String, always with the same locale (English).

I tried to add the following code before getProperty:

```
MLPropertyInterceptor.setMLAware(false);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

But I still the same string regardless of the locale I set. 
How can I address my issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting MLAware to true, to indicate you know about it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public String getLocalizedValue(NodeRef nodeRef, Locale locale)
{
    MLPropertyInterceptor.setMLAware(true); 
    MLText mlProp = (MLText) nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, QNAME_PROP_TYPE_MLTEXT);
    MLPropertyInterceptor.setMLAware(false);
    return mlProp.getValue(locale);
}
```